# Information retrieval Indexing and Ranking Models

Tags: indexing, information-retrieval

[image: question]

I can't think  about structure that match to this question (a).

I thought about idea of posting list of 100x100 +1 entries that contain the exact data of any pixel but it's seem to me wasted idea.

And if I could get some help in the next questions (b,c), I don't understand how I need to thing on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an idea which you can try out.

Since we have both image and its captions, my ideas is to extract different type of information from image and store them as text along with the caption. When a user will submit a text query and/or an image, we need to convert them to a search query. Ranking model means you need to score the indexed documents (image + caption) based on similarity and some pre-defined score (if any).

With images, we can do several things: (See [reference](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-image-search-engine-work/answer/Sam-Gendler?srid=nYmP))

(1) We can run the image through a character recognition routine to extract any words out of signage visible in the photo. (or to read the text of an image meme, for example)

(2) We can recognize any famous landmarks. (and we have sophisticated techniques for recognizing them from any angle)

(3) We can recognize faces - of celebrities and famous people or, if talking about your private photos being indexed in the google photos search, we can recognize your family and friends from other photos.  Even if we don't have names, we can potential spot familiar faces and group them together in the index.  We can also recognize pets.

(4) We can recognize objects - vehicles, buildings, animal species.

The list of potential things we could extract from a photo and its caption is pretty long and varied, but some things obvious deliver higher quality terms than others. All extracted features are not necessarily sufficiently relevant.  For example, features extracted from caption should get more emphasis while computing relevance score.

Similarly, reading the text of a t-shirt that appears in a photo isn't nearly as useful as reading the street signs and store signs, which can easily allow us to figure out a location.

So when we are looking for things to put in the index, we build up a big long list of things associated with the photo, along with some information about our confidence that those terms accurately reflect the content of the photo. We can adjust those scores over time by determining how many people click on an image after searching for a particular term.  If it gets lots of clicks, then it is probably reasonable to crank the score for that term way up. If it never gets clicked, relative to other photos near it on the results, we can lower it.

When user submits a query and a photo, we have to run our feature extraction policy and convert it to a search query. Then we have to figure out the set of photos that have terms that match the query. Then we have to rank those photos according to relevance, based on the scores of the terms that match. Then we can show the result to the user.

Feature extraction from images and computing relevance score based on the extracted features is not an easy thing. What type of ranking model will give you good result largely depends on the extracted features (features mean keywords associated with images) and how precisely your system can put weight on the terms related to the images.

Once you can convert the caption and/or images to text information, you can use ranking functions like [Okapi BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) which is used by search engines to rank matching documents according to their relevance to a given search query.

Comment: But i have images in pixels terms and i need to use the pixels in the index so i dont understand how am I supposed to pump information out of a displayed image in pixels

Comment: images generally given as set of pixel values. usually images are given as a 3 dimensional matrix. for example, if you have 128 X 64 size image, you will store it in a (128 X 64 X 3) array where 3 represents RGB values of one pixel. so, we can extract features from pixel values and my proposed approach will work. i guess you should do some literature survey to get deeper knowledge about image processing/matching systems.